# Finding identity of a given binary operation (*) given by: $x*y = y +9$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

If the binary operation is given as : $x*y = y +9$, then need find the four properties as:

1. Is commutative operation? => need find if $x*y = y*x$, which is not possible, as $x$ may not equal $y$.
2. Is associative operation? => As  <del>not commutative, so not associative,</del> commutativity and associativity can be independent of each other, so check by: $(x*y)*z = (y+9)*z = z+9$, while $x*(y*z) = x*(z+9) = z + 18$. So, not associative.
3. Finding identity if exists? => To ascertain identity($e$) exists, need a proof like: $$ (x*e) = x = (e*x)$$ This means : $e+9 = x = x +9  \implies e+9 =x, 9=0$ hence no identity as $9 \ne 0$.
4. If identity exists, then finding inverse.

=> The answer states that identity exists, with no further value or explanation.

Comment: Commutative and associative are independent. A binary operation can be both, neither, or either one without the other. So you will need to do number 2 the direct way.

Comment: @Arthur  Thanks for reminding that. So, in that case I feel it is always left - to - right ordering.

Comment: The answers depend on the set on which the operation is defined! Should we assume $\Bbb R$ here?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I think only integers, as nthing is stated explicitly; else you can take reals too.

Comment: Your definition of identity is wrong. $e$ is a left identity if $e*y=y$ for all $y$, a right identity if $x*e=x$ for all $x$, and finally an identity if it is both left and right identiy.

Comment: @jiten "Nothing is stated explicitly" is a bad idea for a problem statement. However, whatever set $S$ we have to suppose this is defined for, it seems to be safe to assume that $S$ is a subset of a set that contains $9$ and where addition is understood; also, that $y\in S$ implies $y+9\in S$. At any rate, $S$ seems to contain at least two elements, a fact that is needed for for most parts of the problem

Comment: As for whether or not a left-identity exists... assuming that we *are* in fact working in the integers or some other collection of finite inputs, then note that regardless the value of $e$ one has $e*y=y+9\neq y$ and so identity does not in fact exist.  (*This does assume that $y\neq y+9$ for at least one value of $y$ in our domain.  There are some more exotic cases where we might say that $y=y+9$, for example in $\Bbb Z_9$, or our domain being $\{\infty\}$ in the context of the extended real or complex numbers, we would have $\infty+9$ "equals" $\infty$.*)

Comment: @Arthur Though here we *can* disprove associativity and commutativity with a single calculation: For arbitrary $x$,  $x*(x*x)=(x*x)+9=x+18\ne x+9 =(x*x)*x$ :)

Comment: @JMoravitz sounds abstract.

Comment: @Arthur Please clarify how proved both properties' failure in one go. Also, $(x*x)*x => (x + 9)*x => x+9 + 9.x$.

Comment: @Jiten Do not confuse $*$ with multiplication.  Although true that *multiplication* will distribute over addition, it is not true that our currently unnamed binary operation that we are discussing in this problem will distribute.  $(x*x)*x=(\color{blue}{x+9})*\color{red}{x}$.  We were told that $\color{blue}{x}*\color{red}{y}=\color{red}{y}+9$, that is to say, when we apply $*$ to a pair of numbers, the result is the right number plus nine.  In the same way $(\color{blue}{x+9})*\color{red}{x}=\color{red}{x}+9$.

Comment: As for how *Hagen*'s comment (*not arthur's*) shows that $*$ is neither associative nor commutative (*assuming we are working in a scenario where $x+18\neq x+9$*), If it *was* associative we would require that $(x*y)*z=x*(y*z)$ for all triplets $x,y,z$, and would in particular need to be equal in the case that all of $x,y,z$ happened to be the same value.  Further, if it *was* commutative then we would need $x*y=y*x$ for any pair $x,y$, and would in particular need to be true in the case that $y$ happened to be $(x*x)$.  (*again, some exotic contexts it is associative and commutative*)

Comment: @JMoravitz I have corrected in the OP, please vet it.

Comment: Are you sure the operation isn’t $x*y=x+y+9$?

Comment: @egreg Yes, it is from a book's accompanying web-site for practice questions. If you want, can give link too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your operation is not commutative because $x*y=y+9$ while $y*x=x+9$ and these two numbers are not always the same unless the set on which the relation is defined has only one element.

Your operation is not associative, because $(x*y)*z =z+9$ and $x*(y*z)=(y*z)+9=z+18$ Which are not necessarily the same unless you are in $Z$  $mod(9)$

Your operation does not have an identity because if $e$ is the identity then $e*e=e$ implies $e+9=e$ which is not true unless your are working in integers $mod(9)$,in which case every element would be an identity.Since the identity is unique, the only possible case is if your set has only one equivalence class of  $Z$ $ mod(9)$.

Comment: Sounds good, but what application a single equivalence class can have. Also, no commutative or associative properties. So, must be some new structure.

Comment: Good point. We need a wider scope here.